# I want to retrieve a blob from database sqlite3 and convert it into image

Tags: python, image, tkinter, blob

I got this `Treeview` image table instead of image

[image]

```py
global img, filename
self.fob = open(filename, 'rb')
self.fob = self.fob.read()
entities = (self.makecb.get(), self.modelcb.get(),self.Yearcb.get(), self.Transmissioncb.get(),self.Fuelcb.get(),self.colorcb.get(),self.Enginedisplacementcb.get(),self.PreviousownersE.get(), self.Vehicleorigincb.get(),self.mileagecb.get(), self.numofpasscb.get(),self.lincesplatenum.get().replace(" ", ""), self.fob,
self.sunroofcheck, self.leatherseatcheck,self.sensorcheck, self.cameracheck, self.AlloyWheelscheck,
self.centrallockcheck, self.monitorcheck, self.alarmsystemcheck, self.Daylightledcheck, self.Airbagcheck,
self.Seller_name.get(), self.cashepayments.get(), self.price.get(), self.lincses_start_date_E.get(),
self.linces_expiredate_E.get(), self.insurancecomp_E.get(), self.insurancecomtype_cb.get())
self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()

self.cursorObj.execute(
            '''INSERT INTO Vechicle_info(carmake, carmodel, caryear, cartransmition, carfuel, carcolor, carengine, carpreviousowners, carorigin, carmileage, carnumofpassengers, carlincesplatenum, image, Sunroof, leatherseat, sensor, camera, AlloyWheels, centrallock, monitor,  alarmsystem,  Daylightled, Airbag, sellerrname, paymentmethod, price, Licensesdatestart, Licensedateexpire, insurancecompanyname, insurancetype) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
            entities)
self.con.commit()
self.cursorObj.close()
```

question:
I want to retrieve the blob from the sqllite3 database with other values, and insert it into treeview table using tkinter. when inserting those values into the table i got these type of binery on the on the image column \xfa\xf4\xe9\xd0\xd2\xd2\xc2\x8c\x193\xa0\xab\xab\xcb\x96Q\xcaf\ so how to fetch the image from database and then convert it to image and insert this image into treeview table tkinter.

Comment: Do you know what type of image it is supposed to be?

Comment: Do you have the code that inserted it into sqlite? Do you know the dimensions of the image (in pixels wide by pixels tall) and the number of bytes in the binary blob?

Comment: @kpie thank you for your response this the first section of the code:
self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
        self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()
        self.my_row=self.cursorObj.execute('SELECT image, price, carlincesplatenum, caryear, carmodel, carmake FROM Vechicle_info')
        self.cars_expense_output = self.cursorObj.fetchall()

self.imglist=[]
        for record in self.cars_expense_output:
            stream=io.BytesIO(record[0])
            img=Image.open(stream)
            img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

Comment: @kpie and this is the second:
#img.thumbnail((50,50))
            self.carstoselecet_expensetree.insert(parent="",index=END,image=img,values=(record[1],record[2],record[3],record[4],record[5],record[6]))
            self.imglist.append(img)

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for your response this the first section of the code: self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db') self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor() self.my_row=self.cursorObj.execute('SELECT image, price, carlincesplatenum, caryear, carmodel, carmake FROM Vechicle_info') self.cars_expense_output = self.cursorObj.fetchall() self.imglist=[] for record in self.cars_expense_output: stream=io.BytesIO(record[0]) img=Image.open(stream) img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

Comment: @MarkSetchell  and this is the second:
 #img.thumbnail((50,50)) self.carstoselecet_expensetree.insert(parent="",index=END,image=img,values=(record[1],record[2],record[3],record[4],record[5],record[6])) self.imglist.append(img)

Comment: @kpie
I am trying to add an image into the first column of  6 columns Treeview table but I got binary instead of an image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I am trying to add an image into the first column of 6 columns Treeview table but I got binary instead of an image.

Comment: You should update your question instead of putting code in comments.  Also you need to show how you insert image into database.

Comment: If the image stored in the database is raw data, then you can simply use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=record[0])`.  Also why there are six values in `values` option? There should be only five values after excluding the image.  You can use `values=record[1:]` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=record[0]) and i got this error:
  img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data=record[0]))
TypeError: 'data' is an invalid keyword argument for BytesIO()

and the six values its due to the six columns in the Treeview table

Comment: Please do not put code in comments where it is unformatted and hard to read. Click `edit` under your question and add it in there instead. Please show the code that **inserts** the image into the database. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image stored into database is raw data like below example:

```py
cnx = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# sample code to insert record to database
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample (image BLOB, name TEXT)')
with open('sample.png', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?)', (data, 'Sample'))
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Then you can use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=...)` to create the image to be used in tkinter application.

Below is an example:

```py
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=100) # because the image is around 100x100

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=['Name'], height=2)
tree.pack()

tree.heading('#0', text='Image')
tree.heading('Name', text='Name')

cnx = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sample')
imglist = []
for rec in cursor:
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=rec[0])
    tree.insert('', 'end', image=img, values=rec[1:])
    imglist.append(img)
cursor.close()
cnx.close()

root.mainloop()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Off-topic question: Can only the #0 column contain image?

Comment: @CoolCloud What I know is YES.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for your response, I appreciate it.
I tried to apply your script code, but the image column is gone, and the Treeview table has only 5 columns instead of 6 columns, is there any chance to post my code and tell me what's wrong with it, I am stuck in this issue for 2 weeks

Comment: @asaadkittaneh You can update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks you very much it worked :) but there is a problem with the image size and the position of the records on each column.